# "Login prompt" in python

Tags: python, tty

is it possible to get a Linux login prompt in python, for example with python `tty` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tty.html)?

My overall goal is to connect a two line LCD to a Raspberry Pi and use it as the only display.

Example:

```
Welcome to Raspbian (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-generic x86_64)

Last login: Tue Jun 21 17:44:05 2011

login:user
password:

$>
```

Comment: Do you just need a login prompt, or do you need a whole shell? Because if you need the whole shell there's no reason to code your own login prompt, just act as a proxy toward the shell ant let it handle the logins

Comment: yeah, i need a whole shell to use interactively with a connected keyboard. Maybe there is an even simpler solution that does not need python tty

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with Raspbery PI but in my mind you'd just need to connect to a shell it hosts (for instance through SSH) which would be configured to display on your LCD screen

Comment: BTW if you don't get any satisfying answer there's a [stackexchange dedicated to Raspbery PIs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) on which you might get better results